# Citation problem using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I changed from `natbib` to `biblatex`. Now I have a strange problem concerning my citations:

if i do
`\cite[][3.4.5]{bar}` it will render to something like

> [BAR90, p. 3.4.5]

As I use the section number and not the page number for referencing my citation, I don't want biblatex to render my citation to "p."

What I want is

`\cite[][3.4.5]{bar}` ->

> [BAR90, 3.4.5]

So I want the text in the square brackets printed directly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}` to your preamble.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It happens from time to time that one's question has been asked and answered before -- don't let that discourage you from asking other questions!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to find similar threads, but i didn't find it. But nevertheless it works for me now :-) Thanks!